# How to know which task is being executed with rake

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task

I'd like to know from within a rake ask what is the name of the task that is being executed? How to do this? For example, in the code bellow, when I run `rake my_incredible_task`, it should print "my_incredible_task":

```
  task :boot do
    task_name = <what comes here?>
    puts task_name
  end

  task :my_incredible_task => [:boot] do
    #do some stuff
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is a way out of the box, however you can do something like this:

```
require 'rake'

module Rake
  class Application
    attr_accessor :current_task_name
  end

  class Task
    alias :old_execute :execute
    def execute(args=nil)
      Rake.application.current_task_name = @name
      old_execute(args)
    end
  end
end


namespace :so do

  task :my_task do
    puts Rake.application.current_task_name
  end
end
```

Not sure how this will work out with tasks that run in parallel...

Comment: Thanks. I use this to log the last executed task  in `END` in case of an error. As a one-liner: `END { if $!;         LOG.info("There was an error '%s', last task was <%s>" % [$!, Rake.application.current_task_name.inspect]); end }`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parameter in the block :

```
task :my_incredible_task do |t|
    puts t.name
end
```

**EDIT**

You could use methods instead :

```
  task :boot do |t|
    boot(t.name)
  end

  task :my_incredible_task do |t|
    boot(t.name)
    #do some stuff
  end

def boot task_name
   # do stuff
end
```

Comment: I changed the question a little bit to reflect the real problem.